# Get data of specific node element on click

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get specific data depending on which node element the user is clicking. I have 4 elements that I have targeted using the querySelectorAll code. What I want to accomplish is that if I click the first element I will console.log that specific data, and if I select the third element I will get that data logged. I've tried a couple of things, but haven't got it to work yet.

```js
function selectedSplit() {
 var macroSplits = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
  console.log(macroSplits[0].childNodes[3].childNodes[1].innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear where you are using `selectedSplit` - Wether or not it is being used as the event listener return function. But using an `onClick` event listener, you're return function will be passed the information you need.

If you want to accomplish this in the markup, you could do -

```
<div class='card' onClick="selectedSplit"></div>
```

Then you can simply access it via `event.target`

```
function selectedSplit(event) {
  var thisCard=event.target;
  console.log(thisCard.innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) has the clicked element:

```js
d.onclick = e => console.log(e.target)
```

```html
<div id=d>
 <button><b>b</b></button>
 <button><i>i</i></button>
 <button><u>u</u></button>
 <button><s>s</s></button>
</div>
```